# Object Oriented Java Point and Method Inheritance

Tags: java, object, inheritance

So right now I have a couple of classes:

file 1

```
package simplestart;

import simplegui.SimpleGUI;
public class Point {
    int x, y;
    public Point(int a, int b){
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
    }
    public void drawLine(Object data, SimpleGUI sg){    
        Node current = new Node(data);     
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return(x + " " + y);
    }
}
```

file 2

```
package simplestart;
import simplegui.SimpleGUI;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SimpleStart {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x, y;
        SimpleGUI sg = new SimpleGUI();
        sg.setTitle("Shape Abstraction");
        sg.centerGUIonScreen();
        LinkedList l1 = new LinkedList();
        File fl = new File("shapelist.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fl);
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            x = scan.nextInt();
            y = scan.nextInt();
            Point p = new Point(x, y);
            l1.insertFirst(p);
        }
        l1.traverseList(l1, sg);
        l1.abstractList(l1, sg);
    }
}
```

file 3

```
package simplestart;
public class Node {
    Object data;
    Node next;

    public Node(Object data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

file 4

```
package simplestart;

import simplegui.SimpleGUI;

public class LinkedList {
    Node START;
    public LinkedList(){
        START = null;
    }
    public void insertFirst(Object data){
        Node n = new Node(data);
        n.next = START;
        START = n;
    }

    public void traverseList(Object data, SimpleGUI sg){
        Node current = START;
        int x, y, ex, ey;
        while(current != null){        
            //This is where I'm trying to pull the data from Class Point
            //The error that appears is can't find symbol int x
            x = current.data.x;
            y = current.data.y;
            ex = current.next.data.x; 
            ey = current.next.data.y;
            sg.drawLine(x, y, ex, ey);
            //toString() is an override method in Class Point
            System.out.println(current.data);
            //However, this doesn't work... which I don't get cause it's also a method in Class Point like toString()
            current = current.next;   
        }
    }
    public void abstractList(Object data, SimpleGUI sg){
        Node current = START;
        Node temp = START;
        current = current.next;
        int lp, pr, rl, s;
        while(current.next != null){
            lp = current.next.data.x ­ current.data.x;
            pr = current.next.next.data.x ­ current.next.data.x;
            rl = current.next.next.data.x ­ current.data.x;
            s = lp + pr ­ rl;
            current.next.data = s;
            temp = current.next;
            current = current.next.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I'm taking a point in file 1, adding those points onto a linked list in file 2 in the form of nodes in file 3 and iterating over them in file 4.  However, when current.data should be each node with points, I'm not able to access the method "getX()" or even current.data.x.  I'm curious as to why this is and can't for the life of me figure it out.  Any help would be greatly necessary!

Comment: `getX()` is a public method of `Point`. So you should be able to access that method on your `p` variable in file 2

Comment: right but assuming that the object data is a linked list full of points, why am i not able to call current.data.x or current.data.getX()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't access the point on data is, that the `data` property of `Node` is of type `Object`.

If you want to get that property you could for example either

- Cast the property to `Point`

  `((Point)current.data).x`
- Introduce your own `Node` class which has a property of type `Point` (could be generic as well)

As Andy pointed out, I also strongly recommend to implement your own node class. That has the advantage, that you will have the language support and you don't need to cast and in case your node data type will change you will not run into a runtime exception - the compiler will tell you.

Comment: I hope that the immediate fix you went for is the second suggestion here. The first is unsafe, since you can add anything into the list.

Answer (score 1):

The data in Node is of type Object, it is not casted anywhere to type Point. THere is method toString() in Object class, but no getX() method.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't storing `Point` references in your `Node`, you are storing `Object`: this includes `Point`, but also includes every other class, i.e. classes on which this method is not defined.

Because there is no way to know statically whether a particular Node's data is a Point or not, the compiler has to assume the "lowest common denominator", which is `Object`, and so will only allow you to invoke methods defined on Object.

You need either to specialise your list to hold `Point` references, or to make it generic so that it can hold anything *but in a type-safe way*, i.e. you (or rather, the compiler) can know that the instances are actually Points.

```
public class Node<T> {
  T data;
  Node<T> next;
  public Node(T data){
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Woah, i didn't realize you updated this answer a bunch.  This is great though, using generics makes this a lot more smooth but the guy above answered the question first in a way that fixed my code immediately :) I appreciate this help though!!!

Comment: Using generics is a much better approach than casting. Blindly casting is unsafe, and is exactly what generics is designed to remove the need for.